# Meteor - IF is a facebook user then display something

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

Well i don't know if it's possible but i want something that works like 
{{#if currentUser}}
bla bla bla
{{/if}}
but with facebook only. It's for a custom facebook comments (i don't like the official one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store a user that logs in with Facebook your users collection obtains a field called services. Here is how I handle images:

```
serviceImageUser = function () {

    var user= Meteor.user();

    if(!user)
        return;

    if (user.services)
    {
        if (user.services.facebook)
            return user.services.facebook.picture;
        if (user.services.twitter)
            return user.services.twitter.profile_image_url;
        if (user.services.google)
            return user.services.google.picture;
        if (user.services.instagram)
            return user.services.instagram.profile_picture;
    }
    else
    {
        return user.profile.userProfile.picture;
    }
};
```

You need to add 2 packages to get the Facebook login functionality working.

```
meteor add accounts-facebook
meteor add service-configuration
```

The accounts-facebook plugin enables facebook login and service-configuration allows to store the setup for our Facebook app’s ids.

As for templates:

```
<template name="name">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        {{currentUser.services.facebook.picture}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks!, now my comments looks amazing with the profile picture

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is to publish a field from the user connected services collection and check if the field is available on the client.

```
// overpublish the default user publication with an excerpt
// of its facebook connected service
Meteor.publish("currentUserFacebookName", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {
    fields: {
      // let's publish the name, but could be something else
      "services.facebook.name": 1
    }
  });
});
```

Then on the client you can write the corresponding helper :

```
Meteor.subscribe("currentUserFacebookName");

Template.registerHelper("currentFacebookUser", function(){
  return Meteor.users.findOne({
    "services.facebook.name": {
      $exists: true
    }
  });
});
```